# Creating custom Count Vectorizer with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to create a custom CountVectorizer with Python and Scikit-Learn lib.
I wrote a code that extracts phrases from Pandas dataframe with TextBlob lib, and I want from my Vecotrizer to count those phrases.

My code:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd

my_list = ["I want to buy a nice bike for my girl. She broke her old bike last year.", 
        "I had a great time watching that movie last night. We shouuld do the same next week", 
        "Where can I buy some tasty apples and oranges? I want to head healthy food", 
        "The songs from this bend are boring, lets play some other music from some good bands", 
        "If you buy this now, you will get 3 different products for free in the next 10 days.", 
        "I am living in a small house in France, and my wish is to learn how to ski and snowboad",
        "It is time to invest in some tech stock. The stock market is will become very hot in the next few months",
        "This player won all 4 grand slam tournaments last year. He is the best player in the world!"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"TEXT": my_list})

final_list = []
for text in df.TEXT:
    
    blob = TextBlob(text)
    result_list = blob.noun_phrases
    print(result_list)
    final_list.extend(result_list)

print(final_list)
```

I know that I can create a CountVectorizer like this when I'm working with Sciki-Learn:

```
features = df.iloc[:, :-1]
results = df.iloc[:, -1]

# vectorizer
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('vector title', CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 4), max_features = 1000, stop_words = 'english'), 'TEXT')])

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 75, n_estimators = 125, random_state = 42)
pipeline = Pipeline([('transformer', transformerVectoriser),
                     ('classifier', clf)])


cv_score_acc = cross_val_score(pipeline, features, results, cv=5, scoring = 'accuracy')
```

But how can I create a vectorizer from phrases that I extracted previously?
For example, extracted phrases from the text that is in `my_list` are:

```
['nice bike', 'old bike', 'great time', 'tasty apples', 'healthy food', 'good bands', 'different products', 'small house', 'france', 'tech stock', 'stock market', 'grand slam tournaments']
```

How to create custom count vectorizer were features would be the phrases that I listed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you initialize `CountVectorizer(vocabulary=noun_phrases, ...)` you should get the desired effect:

```
noun_phrases = ['nice bike', 'old bike', 'great time', 'tasty apples', 'healthy food', 'good bands', 'different products', 'small house', 'france', 'tech stock', 'stock market', 'grand slam tournaments']

cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', vocabulary=noun_phrases, ngram_range=(2, 4))
res = cv.transform(my_list)
res.todense()

>>>
matrix([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: If I add vocabulary, why am i adding ngram_range?
If my vocabulary have (for example) 6000 phrases between 1 and 6 words, why am I adding ngram_range?

Comment: Because `CountVectorizer` does some text processing prior to looking it up in the dictionary. It first removes `stopwords` then creates sliding windows of different lengths and only after that looks up the dictionary. So if your `noun phrases` dictionary has entries 1-6 words long, you have to set `ngram_range` to `(1,6)`. You can see that in the sentence with "france" the feature is not counted, exactly bc it is a single word and `CountVectorizer` was set  to look for only bigrams to 4-grams.

Comment: One more question, if my phrase is  "red apple", and in text i have "red apples", should I change the analyzer to "char"?

Comment: I would recommend to start with applying stemming or lemmatization to the original text. Using characters or subwords as features demand a slightly different approach  to the system design.

Comment: How can I incorporate this in ColumnTransformer? I need to pass column name or column index. What If I have multiple columns, and i want to vectorize one column, and I want to pass the vocab to second column?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the tokenizer function of sklearn CountVectorizer

```py
def noun_phrases_tokenizer(text):
    return TextBlob(text).noun_phrases
    
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=noun_phrases_tokenizer)
transformerVectoriser = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('count', count_vectorizer, 'TEXT')])
transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(df)

print(transformerVectoriser.transformers_[0][1].get_feature_names_out())
# ['different products', 'good bands', 'grand slam tournaments', ...]
```

**Update:** Add lemmatization

```py
import textblob

def lemmatize_noun_phrase(phrase):
    # phrase.lemmatize() not working correctly
    return " ".join([textblob.Word(w).lemmatize() for w in phrase.split(" ")])

def custom_tokenizer(text):
    phrases = textblob.TextBlob(text).noun_phrases
    return [lemmatize_noun_phrase(p) for p in phrases]

print(noun_phrases_tokenizer("I love green apples"))  # ["green apple"]
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=custom_tokenizer)
```

Comment: if my phrase is "red apple", and in text i have "red apples", tokenizer will not recognize that, right?
Should I add analyzer= word or analyzer=char?

Comment: You can lemmatize both your text and your phrases, to transform both to "red apple". I updated my answer.